# How to set value for all the objects in array for javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

How to set value for all the items inside an array?

For example, I have the array: `["chin","eng","maths"]`

I want to set it to `{"chin" :true,"eng":true,"maths":true}`

And push to firebase as a child.

[image]

Comment: You mean changing `["chin","eng","maths"]` to `{"chin" :true,"eng":true,"maths":true}` as a structure? Or as a string? The simple fact of changing `[]` to `{}` means a different structure. ([] = Array, {} = Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to loop through the array using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and add each key to an object:

```js
const keys = ["chin", "eng", "maths"],
      output = {};

for (const key of keys) {
  output[key] = true;
}

console.log(output)
```

Another option is to create a 2D array of key-value pair entries using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create the object

```js
const keys = ["chin","eng","maths"]
const output = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, true]))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const input = ["chin", "eng", "maths"];

let obj = input.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item] = true, acc), {});

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, you can go with `spreading`, but with a little overhead on performance:

```
let obj = input.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, [item]: true}), {});
```

Comment: Does that create a new object each iteration?  Seems expensive.

Comment: Probably just as expensive as doing what youd already be doing without using `reduce`

Comment: "In case performance" - yes when a solution is shorter, performs better and is just as readable, I guess that should be the primary answer.

Comment: @James yeah, you right, I have added a better version without spreading.